# apache.commons.fileupload not working with jquery.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets, apache-commons-fileupload

I'm new to JSP and Servlet and I'm trying to upload a single file and move it to my directory using jQuery.ajax(). When I put `action="servletName"` in my form without ajax, it's working fine, I presume my servlet does work fine (I even tried it using JSP, and it's also good). However when I use ajax, it doesn't do anything. I also tried using the same ajax code with PHP, and everything in PHP is working fine.

Here are my codes btw:

**HTML Form**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmFile">
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

**JS**

```
var fd = new FormData();

$("#frmFile").submit(function(){
   $.ajax({

       type: 'post',
       url: '../init.jsp',
       data: fd,
       processData: false,
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       async: true, //with or without
       success: function(data){
           alert(data);
       }           
   });
   return false;
});
```

**Servlet**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.*;

public class init extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        boolean isMultiPart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        if(isMultiPart){
            DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            String path;
            //path = getServletContext().getRealPath("")+"assets\\uploads";
            path = "C:/Users/M/Desktop";
            try{
                List<FileItem> fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

                for(FileItem items: fileItems){
                    if(!items.isFormField()){
                        String name = new File(items.getName()).getName();
                        items.write(new File(path+File.separator+name));
                    }                        
                }
                out.print("SUCCESSFUL!");
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }else{
            out.print("!multipart");
        }
    }
}
//doGet, doPost, getServletInfo
```

In addition, I'm also confident that my ajax works, because aside from it's working with PHP. It prints (alert) "SUCCESSFUL!" which is coded inside the servlet's try-block.

My question is am I missing something in my servlet code? Or apache.commons.fileupload just blocks ajax requests?

Thanks you!

Comment: Are you saying that your Servlet responds with the word "SUCCESSFUL!" ? Maybe you should add some more print statements to the  response. Maybe print the name of the file and the absolute path and its size.

Comment: Loos like parsing problem , formData is not getting parsed by commons.before anything i would siggrst you totry jquery ajaxfileupload plugin to be sure

Answer (score -1):

Maybe missing following in ajax:
`encType : "multipart/form-data"`